# App close when internet connection is not available

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue when try to open a section of my app when device has no network (the app close suddently), works with firebase realtime database, so maybe should add an if() before get the data from firebase?

```
 if (user != null) {
            getThreads();
       } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you are not logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



public void getThreads() {
    SearchRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(5).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Query ordenar = mDatabase.child("Blocnotas").orderByChild("countthreads");
            threadsList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot messageThreadSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MessageThread messageThread = messageThreadSnapshot.getValue(MessageThread.class);
                if (messageThread != null) {
                    dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    messageThread.thread_id = messageThreadSnapshot.getKey();
                }
                oldestPostidList.add(messageThreadSnapshot.getKey());
                threadsList.add(messageThread);

            }
            threadsAdapter = new ThreadsAdapter(ThreadsActivity.this, R.layout.threads_listview, threadsList, tryList,
                    ThreadsActivity.this, ordenar);
            threadsListView.setAdapter(threadsAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ThreadsActivity.this, "ThreadsActivity: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "the app close suddently" It sounds like your app crashes. When an app crashes, it writes an error and stack trace to its logcat output. Please find those and add them to your question.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.